# Post using spring resttemplate

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

Rest server:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/{code}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String sendMessage(@PathVariable String code) {
    boolean h = true;
    try {
        String trackNum = code.substring(0, 34).trim();
        String eventTime = code.substring(35, 60).trim();
        String userName = code.substring(61, 70).trim();
        String eventDispoCode = code.substring(71, 73).trim();
        String loc = code.substring(73, 82).trim();
        String eventTxt = code.substring(83);

        History histInfo = new History();
        histInfo.setDeviceName(userName+"_WEB");
        histInfo.setLogInId(userName);
        histInfo.setAppVersion("1");
        histInfo.setLocCode(loc);
        histInfo.setUserName(userName);

    h = interceptService.processPackageIntercept(histInfo,loc, trackNum, new LocalDateTime(eventTime));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(h){
        return "true";
    }else{
        return "false";
    }
}
```

In Server `h = interceptService.processPackageIntercept(histInfo,loc, trackNum, new LocalDateTime(eventTime));` this service have methods to save details into DB.

Rest client:

```
    String url =  "http://localhost:8090/packageintercept/rest/";
    String st = (String) restTemplate.postForObject(url, b.toString(), String.class);
```

When I used `getForObject()` I can hit DB to retrieve the data but cannot save it in there. When I changed to `postForObject()` I get `HttpClientErrorException. 403 Forbidden error`

Any suggestions! What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a security layer blocking you?

Comment: turned off security for the rest calls

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. Nothing in your handler method indicates that such a response code should be sent back to the client.

Comment: hmm..what should I do now?

Comment: Check that security is really disabled. Or send an authenticated/authorized request.

Comment: `<security:http pattern="/rest/**" security="none"/>` definitely turned off!

Comment: You are posting to a wrong URL. There is no path variable in your URL only /rest... You are putting, what you want as a path variable, in the body.